# return statement returns nothing in javascript

Tags: javascript, return, return-value

Given a square grid of characters in the range ascii[a-z], rearrange elements of each row alphabetically, ascending. Determine if the columns are also in ascending alphabetical order, top to bottom. Return YES if they are or NO if they are not.

```
  const gridOrig = ["ebacd", "fghij", "olmkn", "trpqs", "xywuv"];

  function gridChallenge(grid) {
    // Write your code here
    let gridOne = [];
    let gridTwo = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
      gridOne.push(grid[i].split(""));
      // console.log(gridOne);
    }//this section makes each element of the array become array

    for (let i = 0; i < gridOne.length; i++) {
      gridTwo.push(gridOne[i].sort());
      // console.log(gridTwo);
    }//this section sort each element of the parent array

    let answer = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < gridTwo.length - 1; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < gridTwo[i].length; j++) {
        if (gridTwo[i][j] <= gridTwo[i + 1][j]) {
          // debugger;
          // console.log("true");
          answer.push("YES");
        } else if (undefined) {
          answer = "NO";
        } else {
          // console.log("false");
          answer.push("NO");
        }
      }
    }
    // console.log(answer);

    let finalAns = "NO";
    if (answer.includes("NO")) {
      finalAns = "NO";
    } else {
      finalAns = "YES";
    }
    console.log(finalAns); //I can see it on the console

    return finalAns; // this returns nothing
  }

  gridChallenge(gridOrig);
```

Answer (score 1):

It does return the result, you just don't use it. Try this:

```
const gridChallengeResult = gridChallenge(gridOrig); // saving returned value to variable
console.log(gridChallengeResult) // logging it to the console
```